# How to Implement Long Press back Button Navigation Pop to respective controller in the navigation stack when navigation bar is hidden

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios14

In my Project, I have kept the navigation bar hidden, starting from my root navigation controller. I have created a custom header view (which consists of one back button and title)in all my controllers which are being pushed to the navigation stack. How can I achieve long press back button navigation stack pop to any controller in the stack feature (ios 14  onwards )[image]

Comment: Please refere this link : https://sarunw.com/posts/what-should-you-know-about-navigation-history-stack-in-ios14/

Comment: No, that one didn't help. There is no information about how to achieve this ios14 long press back button when your navigation bar is hidden or if you are using a custom back button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all possible ways but no luck. So I tried with **UIMenu** and add it to my button it helped. you can check this link which might help to achieve the above feature by adding **UIMenu on UIButton**
*[UIMenu In Action](https://morioh.com/p/3ef21642ea0a)*